# Porting OpenGL glBegin() to OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl, opengl-es

How would the following sequence from normal OpenGL be translated to OpenGL ES?

```
    displayList = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(displayList, GL_COMPILE);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glNormal3f(n1.x, n1.y, n1.z);
        glVertex3f(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
        glNormal3f(n2.x, n2.y, n2.z);
        glVertex3f(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);
        glNormal3f(n3.x, n3.y, n3.z);
        glVertex3f(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);
    }
    glEnd();

    glEndList();
    glCallList(displayList);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not directly translate this to OpenGL ES. There are no display lists there and you need to use vertex arrays. It's a different, and actually the preferred way to submit geometry data. I suggest you look up tutorials on Vertex Arrays, and for openGL-ES 2 Vertex Buffer Objects (VBOs) as well.

Comment: Thank you. I need to figure out the connection between vertices and vertice normals (and faces too) since I want to render a model imported from an .obj file.

Comment: @hooch: Nothing has deluded people more about the nature of vertices, than the OpenGL immediate mode API. *Here's the most important piece of information you'll ever get about vertices:* **Vertices are the whole tuple of [position, normal, color, texture coordinates, etc.].** It's a common misconception, proliferated by the bad design of the OpenGL immediate mode API, that `position == vertex`, but this simply is wrong. The whole thing matters. When you call `glVertex` all the other attribute values set before are "copied" into the vertex.

Comment: @hooch: What this means is, that if you change only one of the attributes, be it color, normal, or anything else associated with a vertex, you get a wholly different vertex.